# Iron Router named routes pathFor is null when using arg

Tags: meteor, iron-router

The Iron Router / Meteor examples all seem to use `_id` in the named routes, which works. However, I am missing something in order to use a named route from another key in a collection other than `_id`. Specifically, I am using the `tag` key.

**'/tags' route**

This tag list route works as expected: http://localhost:3000/tags

```
Router.route('/tags', {
  name: 'demoTagsList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('tags');
  },
  data: function() {
     return Tags.find();
   }
});
```

The `pathFor` for `demoTagItem` works as expected

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'demoTagsList'}}">Tags</a>
```

As does `Router.routes['demoTagsList'].url()` --> `"http://localhost:3000/tags"`

**'/tags/:_tag' route**

This specific tag route also works as expected and returns the appropriate data: http://localhost:3000/tags/foo-tag

```
Router.route('/tags/:_tag', {
  name: 'demoTagItem',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('itemsFromTag', this.params._tag);
  },
  data: function() { return Posts.find({tags: this.params._tag}); }
});
```

However, the `pathFor` for each `demoTagItem` route results in `null`.
`Router.routes['demoTagItem'].url()` --> "http://localhost:3000null"

The template code:

```
<template name="demoTagsList">
  <h2>Demo Tag list</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each tags}}
      <li class="tag"><a href="{{pathFor 'demoTagItem'}}">#{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

What needs to happen to set the router path so that `pathFor` picks up `{{name}}` and builds the link as `tags/tag-name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [pathFor docs](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor) you'll see that the function requires a `data` context to fill in the parameters in the route. You can explicitly set the `data` with a template helper like so:

```html
<li class="tag"><a href="{{pathFor 'demoTagItem' data=getTag}}">#{{name}}</a></li>
```

where `getTag` is a template helper that returns an object like `{_tag: 'puppies'}`.

However, the path of least resistance is often to set the route params to have the same field name as a tag object would natively. Assuming your tags have a `name` property, you could modify your route like this:

```js
Router.route('/tags/:name', {
  name: 'demoTagItem',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('itemsFromTag', this.params.name);
  },
  data: function() { return Posts.find({tags: this.params.name}); }
});
```

Now your template shouldn't require any modifications from the original code because the context is already a tag. That should be the equivalent of writing `data=this` where `this` looks like `{name: 'puppies'}`.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried explicitly setting the data with the template helper, I wasn't passing a key value pair. The path of least resistance is what I was looking for, so thank you for providing both methods.